# Why is wget not calling my entire web address?

Tags: command-line, wget

I have a test script with the command:

```
wget http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/timeseries?token=000&start=200505010000&end=200510310000&vars=air_temp_high_24_hour,air_temp_low_24_hour,relative_humidity,sea_level_pressure&units=english&output=csv&obtime=local&STID=KPHX
```

yet the output of wget is

```
gdev@gdev-samsung:~/$ ./test
gdev@gdev-samsung:~/$ --2015-06-14 16:56:52--  http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/timeseries?token=f11c52999e0144dcb4461f4fb3ef2b53
Resolving api.mesowest.net (api.mesowest.net)... 63.251.153.118
Connecting to api.mesowest.net (api.mesowest.net)|63.251.153.118|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9560276 (9.1M) [application/json]
Saving to: ‘timeseries?token=f11c52999e0144dcb4461f4fb3ef2b53’

100%[========================================================================>] 9,560,276   1.52MB/s   in 5.9s   

2015-06-14 16:57:01 (1.54 MB/s) - ‘timeseries?token=f11c52999e0144dcb4461f4fb3ef2b53’ saved [9560276/9560276]
```

Is the website link accidently using some sort of special characters that wget is cutting? Thanks for any help

Comment: Try to enclose URL with quotes : `wget 'http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/timeseries?token=000&start=200505010000&end=200510310000&vars=air_temp_high_24_hour,air_temp_low_24_hour,relative_humidity,sea_level_pressure&units=english&output=csv&obtime=local&STID=KPHX'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have special chars in your URL, like `?`.

You best bet would be to enclose the full URL with single quotes so that those special chars will not be handled by the Shell :

```
wget 'http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/timeseries?token=000&start=200505010000&end‌​=200510310000&vars=air_temp_high_24_hour,air_temp_low_24_hour,relative_humidity,s‌​ea_level_pressure&units=english&output=csv&obtime=local&STID=KPHX'
```

---

As a side note : trying your URL i've encountered a "permission denied".

Depending on your authentication method you may have to pass some login :

```
wget --user=user --http-password=pass 'http://....'
```